# Incoming and outgoing calls in the BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

There is a service in which the processed media player would want to do that for an incoming and outgoing call service stopped media player, and at the end of the call flow resumes playback. 
Now only managed to stop playback on incoming and outgoing calls, should add code to play TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: then the talking after a while the music starts, how to fix it?

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
TelephonyManager telManager;
Context context;
boolean startedCall = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


this.context=context;


telManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    try {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
            if(incomingNumber!=null)
            {
                //incoming call
                MediaService.stopMP();
                startedCall  = true;
            }

        break;
        }
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {
            if(incomingNumber!=null)
            {
                //outgoing call
                MediaService.stopMP();
                startedCall  = true;
            }

        break;
        }
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: {
            if(startedCall)
            {
                MainActivity.titleMusic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MainActivity.Play();
                MediaService.startMP();
                startedCall = false;
            }                   

        break;
        }
        default: { }
        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever before ringing the call state should be `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`, Before get incoming call the Call State should be IDEL, So you have to set a flag boolean to Identify the state;

```
    public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    TelephonyManager telManager;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
       this.context=context;    
       private boolean startedCall = false; // New added boolean    
       telManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       telManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);    
    }

    private final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    try {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
                if(incomingNumber!=null) {
                   //incoming call
                   MainActivity.stopMP()
                }    
                break;
            }
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {    
                startedCall  = true; // Newly added code    
               if(incomingNumber!=null) {
                  //outgoing call
                   MainActivity.stopMP();
               }
               break;
            }
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: {
               if(startedCall) {
                   MainActivity.titleMusic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   MainActivity.Play();
                   MediaService.startMP();
               }          
               break;
            }
            default: { }
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {

      }
    }
    };
}
```

Comment: outgoing call does not seem to turn on, and when an incoming also plays on the background of the conversation, the call begins at break buffer again. corrected the code in question

Comment: It can be helpfull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377852/handling-incoming-calls-in-android-application